# Program crashing when deployed on a docker container

Tags: java, docker, or-tools

I have a Java program that use TSP from or-tools. I can run the program locally without any problems. I also tested it on Debian and Alpine using WSL after installing the proper native dependencies.

However, I cannot make it work when running on a container. I already tested several docker images and dependencies installs but the problem persist. When the program is running and the TSP method is requested, instantly the container crashes without any logs, what make things harder to debug.

Here is my current Dockerfile:

```sh
# ======================================================================================================================
# Build Application
# ======================================================================================================================
FROM openjdk:14-alpine as build

VOLUME "/root/.gradle/caches"
USER root
ADD . /build/
WORKDIR /build
RUN ls /build

# Inject native Java libraries (needed for or-tools)
RUN yes | cp -rf ./lib/native/linux/jar/* ./lib # or-tools jar files are here

RUN chmod +x ./gradlew && ./gradlew assemble


# ======================================================================================================================
# Setup Application
# ======================================================================================================================
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:14

VOLUME /tmp
USER root
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/build/libs/service-itinerary-builder-0.1.0.jar app.jar

# Inject native linux libraries (needed for or-tools)
RUN apt install autoconf g++ xfce4-dev-tools libtool zlib1g-dev
COPY --from=build /build/lib/native/linux/lib /lib # or-tools .so files are here


# ======================================================================================================================
# Start Application
# ======================================================================================================================
EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: 1) are you sure mixing an alpine docker image with a debian one is OK, since or tools is a native library so we depend on libmusl or libc IMHO.
2) How did you build or-tools ? don't hesitate to open an github issue so we'll take a look at it, otherwise if we can't reproduce it....